# Replace a back slash in string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string

Hi i tried to replace a back slash in string

```
var str='he\1o';var res = str.replace(/\\/g,'l');console.log(res);
output :"heo"
```

Unable to replace a back slash
Can some one help me on this.

Comment: note: `var str='he\1o'` str has no \ in it - check for yourself

Comment: Start with this: `var str='he\\1o` - then it works.

Comment: Sorry editing the above is there any way in java script to know if my string has a single black slash

Comment: Edited answer if still interested

Answer (score 0):

The string doesn't contain a backslash, it contains the \1 escape sequence.

And if you want a regular expression, you should have a regular expression, not a string.

```
var str = "he\\1o";
var replaced = str.replace(/\\/, "l");
```

**EDIT**

You can also replace `\1` with `ll` and you will achieve the same thing.

```
var str = "he\1o";
var replaced = str.replace(/\1/, "ll");
```